# Haystack django SearchQuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I'm using **Haystack Django** for search engine.

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(**conds)
```

the **conds** may include :

```
conds['name'] = Exact(name)
conds['category'] = Exact(category)
conds['city_id'] = Exact(city_id)
```

but beside I also want to add **list of sub_category** as conditions, so is there any way to add something like

```
conds['sub_category'] = list(city_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the question seem to not clearly, I meant I want to add the key *sub_category* into the dictionary *conds* that values are list.
So i found this way could answer the question above:

```
conds['sub_categary__in']  = sub_category_list
```